# How many reports on YouTube does it take for a comment to be reviewed by YouTube?

Tags: youtube, comments

Title question. By reviewed I mean looked at to see if it breaks YouTube’s guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

It takes exactly one report to take down the comment evaluated as inappropriate. The issue here is the time interval of getting it done. There is a priority queue meaning that comments with more reports are getting evaluated sooner than those with just a few or one report/flag.